# SWIFT: count number of days a cell was marked as completed

Tags: swift, uitableview, date, notifications, uilabel

I am making a Habit Tracking app and want to count how many days a cell was marked as done throughout 7 and 30 days to show the user their success rates through UILabels.

The user swipes the cell to mark it as done, which changes its color.  The colors reset each day. I'm not sure if it would help, but this is the code that keeps track of the day changes and resets the colors (I haven't ran the simulator overnight to see if it works but it runs successfully otherwise):

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: TableViewController]?) -> Bool {
    // day change notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("dayChanged:")), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange, object: nil)
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return true
}
```

Could this block of code be amended to also count the number of days a cell was marked done?  Or is that a whole other thing?  I would think it is a different function, but I'm new to coding and don't know where to proceed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not related but this custom *delegate* method is never going to be called.

Comment: @vadian Yikes, thank you. I put it in the app delegate - though I have no idea if that fixed that problem.

Comment: Duncan's suggestion is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

No, notifications are not appropriate for this.

You probably have a method that gets called when the user swipes a cell to mark an action as done.

Simply add code to that method that fetches a value from `UserDefaults`, increments it, and writes it back to `UserDefaults`.